# Incorrect application version. Expected version "XXX"

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to deploy my symfony2 project on `aws elastic-beanstalk`, but I keep having this error:

```
Command failed on all instances.
Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version "app-3706-170331_113756" (deployment 6).
```

.

```
            i-02ac339ff8d24da60 Severe  3 hours 9   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0.00    0.00    0.1 0.1 99.8    0.0
    Application update failed at 2017-03-31T10:40:17Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_composer_install.sh failed.

    + . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
    ++ export HOME=/root
    ++ HOME=/root
    ++ export COMPOSER_HOME=/root
    ++ COMPOSER_HOME=/root
    ++ export PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=2048M
    ++ PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=2048M
    ++ export PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=4000
    ++ PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=4000
    ++ export PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=On
    ++ PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=On
    ++ export PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS=
    ++ PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS=
    ++ export PHP_ALLOW_URL_FOPEN=On
    ++ PHP_ALLOW_URL_FOPEN=On
    ++ export PHP_ZLIB_OUTPUT_COMPRESSION=Off
    ++ PHP_ZLIB_OUTPUT_COMPRESSION=Off
    ++ export PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT=
    ++ PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT=
    ++ export PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE=UTC
    ++ PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE=UTC
    ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
    + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
    + cd /var/app/ondeck
    + '[' -f composer.json ']'
    + export COMPOSER_HOME=/root
    + COMPOSER_HOME=/root
    + '[' -d vendor ']'
    ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config optionsettings -n aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini -o composer_options
    + PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS=
    + echo 'Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.'
    Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.
    + composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
    - Installing twig/twig (v1.27.0)
    Loading from cache

    - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.8.13)
    Loading from cache

    - Installing symfony/security-acl (dev-master 053b49b)
    Cloning 053b49bf4aa333a392c83296855989bcf88ddad1




Command output has been truncated. Please see logs for more details.
Incorrect application version "app-3706-170331_123438" (deployment 9). Expected version "app-3706-170331_113756" (deployment 6).
```

I have increased Max execution time up to **4000** and  Memory limit up to **2048M**.

In  `.ebextensions` I have the following file:

**project.config**

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/symfony.ini" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upload_max_filesize = 256M
      post_max_size = 256M
```

**main.config**

```
commands:
  01_update_composer:
    command: export HOME=/root && export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update 1.0.0-alpha11

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: HOME
    value: /root
```

**01-increase-timeout.config**

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
      option_name: Timeout
      value: 1000
```